# Setting HTTP headers to retrieve data from member only web page

Tags: c#, http-headers, webclient

Im having a bit of a problem with my C# code and im not sure how to tackle it. Im attempting to DownloadString a webpage that only people that are logged in can see (otherwise it returns a 403 response). So I though the best way to do this was to set the HTTP header cookie value to that of a logged in users. Unfortunately it has not worked. Here's the snippet of code:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "*/*";
web.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = "User cookie";

string pagecontent = web.DownloadString("Forbidden page");
```

When the code is used, I still get a 403 error. I am definitely using a working cookie, i've tested it. What could be going wrong?

In addition to that, how would I grab a cookie from a webBrowser and set the webclient HTTP cookie header to that?

Answer (score 0):

The following method doesn't use the `WebClient` class, but it works:

```
string domain = ...
string url = ...
Cookie cookie = ...

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(domain, cookie);

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```